# Django DRY - How to extend two .html files inside a Django Template?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

**What do I want?**

I want to extend `cards/apps.html` inside `addstudents.html` so that I don't need to write the chucks of codes multiple times. What can I do to extends multiple `.html` files inside DJANGO template?

**Error I am getting**

> 'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template

**WHAT TO DO?**

> NOTE: I don't want to use `{% include %}`, because the situation/condition isn't suitable.

SOME INFORMATION YOU MAY NEED...

> Inside cards/apps.html

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
<div class="card-header py-3">
    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">{{card_title}}</h6>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    {% block card_body %}
    
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

> Inside addstudents.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/panel.html' %}
{% extends 'apps/card.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

{% with card_title='My Card TITLE' %}
{% block card_body %}
...SOME FORM, .... SOME PARAGRAPH
{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

> What's inside layouts/panel.html

`layouts/panel.html` contains some menu and navbars items [including CSS, bootstrap and JS dependencies].

> What's `apps/card.html`?

`apps/card.html` contains the code-snippet of HTML and Bootstrap CARD. And I don't want to write this code multiple times. That's why I want it to be manipulated via `Django Template Tags`.

***HOPE YOU UNDERSTOOD***

Comment: How would you expect Django to merge two base templates if it was possible to extend from both? I think your use case requires the use of `include` directive. Alternatively you can create a second base template that extends from the first one, then let your template extend the second if that makes sense.

Comment: I think you're saying me to load the code inside `'layouts/panel.html'` That'll make the code junky and slow.

Comment: There can be only one parent template. If you want to render the same piece of html in several different places, and don't want to repeat yourslef, include tag can help you - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include . Can you explain why exactly you don't want to use it?

Comment: I already told you that I don't want to use include. I need to write a FEW codes (like HTML-Form) inside `{% block card_body %}`. And I can't do that inside `{% include %}`. Include will load all the code-chunks inside the HTML and `with` can be used to pass some variable which won't satisfy my requirements. So for this  I want some thing like  `{% block card_body %}`

Comment: Can you show the code for your **`layouts/panel.html`** template?

Comment: Sure. HAVE A LOOK: https://codeshare.io/2pdqp6

Comment: `include` is exactly for this use case as @Selcuk and Erlond mentioned. The conflicts you're seeing can be remedied by improving the templates and layout. This feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Nope. `include` will include all the details inside the `.html` file. I want to pass some form-html and variable inside `<div class="card-body">`.  I want my form inside `<div class="card-body">`. Can you do this

Comment: When you say cards/apps.html, I am supposing you mean apps/card.html? both are there in your question. Are they two separate files, or a typo?

Comment: Please get over your irrational include fear. Any solution that works will use include. Live with it.

Comment: I know about include and also use it. But it won't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen those are typos

Comment: @BishwasBhandari, ok. Please edit your question, and if my answer helps, accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is *directly* possible. But here is a work around. In the view which handles `addstudents.html`, add `has_card` to the context as `True`.

`views.py`

```py
def app_students(request):
    # Your code
    return render(request, 'addstudents.html', {'has_card': True})
```

`layouts/panel.html`

```html
[...]
{% if has_card %}
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">{{card_title}}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% block card_body %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
[...]
```

`addstudents.html`

```html
{% extends 'layouts/panel.html' %}
{% with card_title='My Card TITLE' %}
{% block card_body %}
...SOME FORM, .... SOME PARAGRAPH
{% endblock %}
```

So this, if `has_card` doesn't exist, won't have the `card_body` block, but if it does exist as a truthy value, then it will.

Comment: 'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template

Comment: Yeah. Extend only `panel.html`, delete `card.html` or `app.html` or whatever the file with the card design was called, and it should work, if you pass `has_form` to your view.

Comment: @BishwasBhandari, did you try this? It should work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your need.
One way could be to split the responsibilities a bit between the different templates.
From given information it could be possible to put bootstrap/layout stuff in cards/apps.html and add additional blocks for childs to override to just handle the forms and view specific information.

To clarify the inheritance that may resolve the problem:

layouts/panel.html -> apps/card.html -> addstudents.html

The `apps/card.html` overrides `block content` from `layout/panel.html` and adds additional blocks which are used by the `addstudents.html`.

It can also be seen as, in words: addstudents.html extends card.html which extends panel.html.
Afaik you can extend as many times you want, but not use extends twice in the same template.

**cards/apps.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/panel.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">{% block card_title %}{% endblock %}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% block card_body %}
        
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**addstudents.html**

```
{% extends 'apps/card.html' %}

{% block card_title}My Card TITLE{% endblock card_title%}
{% block card_body %}
...SOME FORM, .... SOME PARAGRAPH
{% endblock card_body %}
```

Worth mention is also [{{ block.super }}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) which can be quite useful sometimes if you need to render a "parent".

Comment: What about extending `{% extends 'layouts/panel.html' %}`

Comment: You can extend multiple times, but not extend twice in the same template... in the example gives the following inheritance: layouts/panel.html' -> cards/apps.html -> addstudents.html. Make sense?